# "Не дотянул" — управление

Tags: падежи, управление, родительный-или-винительный

Как правильно: в винительном или родительном падеже?

*Он не дотянул всего **полметра/полуметра** до рекорда трамплина.*

Ничего в словарях, Нацкорпусе и интернете не нашёл по этому поводу. Можно оправдать родительный чем-то помимо отрицания?

Answer (score 3):

1. Как известно, Р.п. заменяет В.п. **в трех темах:** при отрицании, при обозначении одушевленности и при распространении действия на часть предмета. Таким образом,  в нашем случае использование Р.п. связано **с отрицанием.** В словаре есть похожий числовой пример:

**ДОТЯНУТЬ**,  св. 1. что до чего. Протянуть до какого-л. места, предела.  Д. кабель до реки.  6. до чего. Разг. Довести до определённого количества, уровня, степени совершенства. Д. производительность труда до прежнего уровня. **Не дотянули двух процентов до полного плана.**

В текстах также используется Р.п.

Летчик не смог дотянуть **двух километров** до посадочной полосы, но ему удалось посадить машину на территории,

Антокольский не дотянул **трех месяцев** до возраста Якова Семеновича. [Ю. М. Нагибин (1978)]

2. **Но В.п. тоже встречается:**

До векового юбилея княгиня не дотянула **три года.** [Юрий Давыдов (1988-1989)]

При аварийной посадке самолет не дотянул до аэропорта Львова **полтора километра**.

До рекорда катка, установленного три года назад, он не дотянул **всего** **несколько десятых**,  а ближайшего преследователя опередил почти на секунду.

3. Другие проблемы связаны со словом ***полметра***. По мнению Грамоты.ру, в книжной речи при склонении ПОЛ меняется на ПОЛУ,  а разговорной речи первая часть не меняется, например:  полустакана и полстакана (Р.п.). (Вопрос № 303997).

**У Розенталя:**  В составе сложных слов числительное ПОЛ  в косвенных падежах (кроме В.п.) принимает форму ПОЛУ, например: полчаса, за полчаса, в получасе ходьбы, полгода, в течение полугода. **В вариантных формах Р.п.**  *не хватает **получаса** – не хватает **полчаса*** последний вариант является разговорным.

**В словаре Ожегова** несклоняемая форма тоже допускается: ПОЛМЕТРА, половина метра.  Не хватает **полуметра (полметра)** ситца.

4. Также можно обратить внимание на слово ***всего*** с ограничительным значением. О таких словах говорится у Розенталя,  в этом случае рекомендуется В.п.: Он едва не уронил стакан.

[http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm#з_04](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm#%D0%B7_04)  §201. Падеж дополнения при переходных глаголах с отрицанием

5. С учетом всего этого я думаю, что лучше выбрать форму  ***полметра***:

***Он не дотянул всего полметра до рекорда трамплина.***

Даже если это Р.п., можно считать, что корень ПОЛ не склоняется.

Comment: Спасибо большое!